# How copy dependencies from a Maven repository to another

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

for a customer I should connected to a VPN, connect to a Virtual Remote Desktop (VRD) and finally develop the code from here. The VRD is simply slow, develop the code is frustrating.

Considering that the project needs a connection to customer-Nexus repository, I tryed to copy the whole Maven repository from the VRD to the Maven repository in my PC.
But when I try to compile the project (in IntelliJ) I receive this error:

```
com.foo:bar:pom:1.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 ...
```

The dependency com.foo:bar:1.0 is one downloaded from the customer Nexus repository and it is correctly present in my local Maven repository (by manual copy).

Why do Maven start to look for the dependency from the remote repository instead of look for inside my local repository? How can I fix this behaviour?

Many thanks

Comment: You can try a `mvn install -nsu` (nsu for no snapshot updates) it should force to use the local repo instead of trying to update each dependency from a remote repository

Comment: I think its a few problems, the first one its your settings, the other one its you need user the argument in maven to force it to use the local. A good idea could use a local repository, put your library and all the libraries you need there, The following article explain it step by step https://manios.org/2019/08/21/force-maven-offline-execute-goal-dependencies

Comment: If you have copied the whole repository and you don't need anything else, try to compile from the command line using the `-o` switch to force the offline mode.